# adding and removing product from the cart at the same time

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

I have pay pal checkout button on Product page in magento . Clicking on it adds the product with respective quantity to the cart and takes user to the pay pal express checkout page. https://prnt.sc/hv1b1l

Now my problem was If user decides to change the quantity of product on pay pal express checkout page and click browser back button, then they are send to the product page and If they change the quantity and click on pay pal checkout button for checkout process then the product is added to the cart with respective quantity. Say first time 2 quantities of a product was added and second time 3 quantities of the same product was added then this makes total of 5 of the same product in the cart. This should not happen. The cart should update to only 3 products.

What I did for the above problem is I made some changes in addAction function in CartController.php I have added the following code

```
    $returnUrl = $this->getRequest()->getParam('return_url');
    if (strpos($returnUrl, '/paypal/express') !== false) {

        $quote = $cart->getQuote();             
        $existingProducts = array();
        foreach($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
            $existingProducts[$item->getProductId()][] = $item->getItemId();
        }

        $item_id = $existingProducts[(int)$params['product']][0];

        if ($item_id) {
            $this->_getCart()->removeItem($item_id)->save();
        }

        $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);
    }
    /*Code to add product is here*/
```

It checks If I am clicking on pay pal express checkout button on Product page then it checks if the respective product is in the cart then it first removes it from the cart and then the addAction of CartController.php adds it back again with new quantity or parameters.

Now the problem I am facing is if previously I had 2 quantities of a product in the cart and I came back to the product page from pay pal express checkout page and decides to make the quantity 3. I change the quantity to 3 and it works fine. But If I have only 4 quantity of that product in stock then it gives the error "The requested quantity for "Product Name" is not available."

I know this is happening because cart is not getting updated but I could not think of any solution. Please any one can guide me what should I do or try.